# Cast type using an instance

Tags: java

The error:
CAP#1 is not a fresh type

The code:

```
public Boolean isAssigned(HttpServletRequest request, String name, Foo foo) {
    Boolean isAssigned = false;

    if ((foo.getClass()) request.getSession().getAttribute(name) != null) {
        isAssigned = true;
    }

    return isAssigned;
}
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Which part of the if-condition do you want to cast? Right now it looks like you cast the result of `request.getSession().getAttribute(name)` and afterwards check for `!= null` which you can do without casting anyway.

Comment: Oh. I guess it would be useful if I changed the method to execute a method in the bean it casts to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not be what you are looking for but it answers the question in the title.

The `Class<T>` class has a [cast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) method which can cast any object to its own type `T`. Obviously it will throw a `ClassCastException` if the object cannot be cast to that type.

```
public <T> T castTo(Class<T> t, Object o) {
    return t.cast(o);
}

public <T> T castTo(T t, Object o) {
    return (T) castTo(t.getClass(), o);
}

public void test() {
    String s = "Hello";
    Object b = s;
    String c = castTo(String.class, b);
    String d = castTo("Some String", b);
}
```

Comment: @ThreaT - Sorry but your code doesn't make sense so I answered the title of your question *Cast type using an instance*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test whether

```
request.getSession().getAttribute(name)
```

is of type `Foo` and execute a method `method` on it afterwards you could simply try using `instanceof` and `cast`:

```
if (request.getSession().getAttribute(name) instanceof Foo) {
    ((Foo) request.getSession().getAttribute(name)).method();
}
```

Comment: Using `Foo` instead of `foo.getClass()` will give a different result if `foo` is a subclass of `Foo`.

Comment: @Trengot What exactly do you mean by "will give a different result"?

Comment: The program will execute differently depending on which you use when given the same input. If `foo` is of type `SubFoo` (where `SubFoo` extends `Foo`) and the `getAttribute()` call returns a `Foo` (or some other subclass (but not subclass of `SubFoo`)) the if block will be entered if you use `instanceof Foo` and not if you use `instanceof foo.getClass()`